# Laravel Carbon - How to add minutes

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a form where I ask 4 hours, It's morning start and end hour and the same for afternoon.

I'm using `Carbon` but it returns me 0 if I put 30 minutes, it rounds to down.

I try with `diffInHours` and `diffInMinutes` but it rounds always down in both ways.

This is my code example:

```
$startTime1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:s', '09:00');
$startTime2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:s', '10:30');
$startTime3 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:s', '14:00');
$startTime4 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:s', '16:00');
$morningTime = $startTime2->diffInHours($startTime1);
$afternoonTime = $startTime4->diffInHours($startTime3);

$total = $morningTime + $afternoonTime;
```

In `$morningTime` it returns 1 and should return 1,30.
In `$afternoonTime` it returns 2 and it's correct.

If I use with `diffInMinutes` it put 60 in `$morningTime` and 120 in `$afternoonTime`. It's wrong again in morning time.

How can I solve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning seconds `H:s` in the Carbon format, use `H:i`:

```
$startTime1 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', '10:30');
```

And You can use [format()](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting) method to format the difference in time

```
$morningTime = $startTime2->diff($startTime1)->format('%H:%I');
```

**Edit**: there is no way to combine [dateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) instance, but you still can use timestamp:

```
$total_in_seconds = ($startTime2->timestamp - $startTime1->timestamp) + ($startTime4->timestamp - $startTime3->timestamp);

$total = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($total_in_seconds)->format('h:i');
```

Comment: Ok, but after that I have to add $morningTime + $afternoonTime and doesn't work. I have to be a 3,30 value. @YouneL

Comment: It returns me 07:00 ... and should return 03:30 @YouneL

Comment: Yes my mistake, because I did `$startTime4->timestamp - $startTime2->timestamp` it should be `$startTime4->timestamp - $startTime3->timestamp`, I updated my answer